# Search Media by taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy, search, media

How do I search media, based on taxonomy in frontend?

The following query displays what I would like to have returned via search:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'post_status' => 'inherit',

// for PDFs    
'post_mime_type' => 'application/pdf',

// if you need PDFs from a specific media category
'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'media_category', // taxonomy
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => 21 // term id (STATIC id of the media category)
        ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'media_category', // taxonomy
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => 22 // term id I NEED TO SET VIA SEARCH)
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: So you have a custom taxonomy attached to the `attachment` post type? Or are you looking for attachments attached to posts in that taxonomy, e.g. a `post` or `page` in the `media_category` taxonomy?

Comment: Also massive kudos for using taxonomies instead of post meta to do this, a major win for performance

Comment: I am not looking for attachments, but rather want a straight "Media Search" and using taxonomies to filter results.

Comment: Basically: I have a significant collection of PDF I need clients to search. I classify the PDFs using taxonomies and therefor would like to include these taxonomies in my search options. e.g. annual reports vs financial statements.

Comment: But attachments are media! The media library is an archive of posts of type `attachment`. Every upload is a post of type `attachment` that represents a file stored on the server. So yes you *are* looking for attachments, specifically PDF attachments in a particular media category.

Answer (score 1):

To search, use the `s` option as described in the `WP_Query` documentation

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Search_Parameter

> ### Search Parameter
>
> Show posts based on a keyword search.
>
> ```
> s (string) - Search keyword.
> ```
>
> #### Show Posts based on a keyword search
>
> Display posts that match the search term `"keyword"`:
>
> ```
> $query = new WP_Query( array( 's' => 'keyword' ) );
> ```
>
> Prepending a term with a hyphen will exclude posts matching that term. Eg, `'pillow -sofa'` will return posts containing `'pillow'` but not `'sofa'` (available since Version 4.4).